# How to keep track of virtual memory used when running Python code?

Tags: python, memory, ram

I have a Python package I am benchmarking for virtual memory used.

At the moment, this isn't very precise. I submit the script e.g.

```
python script1.py
```

and look at the time and resources used in order to execute.

Is there some package/method to find out where my RAM bottlenecks are? I'm thinking of a tool like

```
ram_used python script1.py
```

that would keep track of how much RAM is used.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: What do you mean with *RAM bottlenecks*? Do you want to know *where* the program is using a lot of memory? Or simply how much?

Comment: The general type of tool is called a `profiler`, and it usually binds to your operating system, rather than a particular language.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Simply how much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is - It's called [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler). Once you've gone through and added the `@profile` decorator to the functions you would like to profile, you can use;

```
python -m memory_profiler example.py
```

Comment: What Python version?  Both 2.7 and 3.5.4 deny any knowledge of `memory_profiler` for me.

Comment: Have you installed it using pip? `pip install -U memory_profiler` works fine for me using python 2.7.1.

Comment: Thanks; my "install" command is aliased to `yum`; `pip` worked, and the profiling worked.

Comment: @TomWyllie This is exceptionally useful for checking individual functions of the Python package. However, it's a bit cumbersome to add decorators to all functions in order to check the entire package. Is there a way to check the virtual memory used for the entire package?

Comment: I've not tested this but my first idea would be to just decorate the entry point to the program, eg your `if __name__ == '__main__'`. Although this may not fit your use case.

Comment: How does it report virtual RAM? As far as I can tell, it's reporting resident RAM only.

Answer (score -1):

There's also `memory_info` `psutil`. https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/

Place at the beginning of the script:

```
import psutil
p = psutil.Process()
```

and given that the code is running correctly, place this on the last line:

```
print(p.memory_info())
```