# How to generate random trace using python?

Tags: python, operating-system, virtual-memory

I'm now studing Paging Policy of OS, and would like to test cache hit rate with different virtual memory trace. For example, a total random trace, and a trace with locality.
I see there is  a`trace` module in python, can I use that to generate the above traces?

Comment: If you found the trace module, you may be able to find the dokumentation of it - what does it have to say about creating random/locallity traces for your purposes... ? I had a look at it and it seems to create traces of a running python program, which modules are loaded etc. Does that sound as if it would do what you want to do it? There is nothing in it that would lead to me thinking it can create random traces ... so what made you think it would do it?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Actually I have also taken a quick look at the docs before I ask here and I didn't find some description related to my need so I opened this question to see if it's possible or there is another way. And the random/locality is what I want to test. You can imagine FIFO and LRU policy may behave same on a random trace, that's what I want to verify.

Comment: A quick search on SO  lead me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44976242/how-to-keep-track-of-virtual-memory-used-when-running-python-code  one answer mentions `memory_profiler` - buy you would have to annotate your functions - it may be a better choice for OS-Paging Policy Tests. Dunno. Much luck with your search here

Answer (score 0):

if you mean hw22 from OS: Three Easy Pieces by Remzi H. Arpaci-Dusseau and Andrea C. Arpaci-Dusseau (University of Wisconsin-Madison) [https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/)

Then i believe it's a typo. Question 1 refers to address traces with a provided random seed. {0,1,2}.

Question 3 is asking for you to generate a random trace (i.e. not with a random see of {0,1,2}) and then analyze how the different policies would do on your trace generated. It says use python or perl, probably typo? The source code that accompanies the text includes a python file that fills an array representing a buffer then there's logic for it to process the answer.